# For loop with Regex not behaving as desired

Tags: python, regex

I have a string value called 'match3g' in my code that prints data in the following format:

```
10272,201,Halifax,1,3333,1,33,2,33
,10272,989,Forest Green,2,3331,3,33,9,31
,10272,203,Lincoln,3,1333,6,13,4,33
,10272,206,Barnet,4,3303,11,30,1,33
,10272,199,Wrexham,5,3033,15,03,3,33
,10272,749,Kidderminster,6,1331,2,33,13,11
,10272,205,Macclesfield,7,3311,8,31,8,31
,10272,6106,Eastleigh,8,3310,7,31,10,30
,10272,1392,Aldershot,9,3031,5,31,12,03
,10272,921,Gateshead,10,3310,16,30,6,31
,10272,164,Grimsby,11,1113,18,11,5,13
,10272,991,Woking,12,3111,19,11,7,31
,10272,204,Torquay,13,0311,4,31,17,01
,10272,919,Southport,14,0013,14,03,18,01
,10272,185,Bristol Rovers,15,1003,9,13,22,00
,10272,909,Dover,16,0013,13,03,19,01
,10272,3551,Braintree Town,17,0300,10,30,20,00
,10272,1389,Altrincham,18,0030,12,03,21,00
,10272,213,Chester,19,0030,24,00,11,03
,10272,6140,Dartford,20,0101,20,01,15,10
,10272,1395,Welling,21,1001,17,11,24,00
,10272,982,Telford,22,1000,22,00,14,10
,10272,913,Nuneaton,23,0100,23,00,16,10
,10272,2792,Alfreton,24,0000,21,00,23,00
```

I want to split the numeric string after the 4th comma in each line using commas. I have some code that will achieve this, but only parses the last line:

```
regex2 = re.compile(r'\d+(?=(?:,[^,]+){4}$)',re.S)
regexer2 = re.search(regex2, match3g)
regexer2 = regexer2.group()
regexer3 = ','.join(list(regexer2))
regexs2 = str(regexer3)
print "Test = ", regexs2.decode()
```

This prints a result of:

```
Test = 0,0,0,0
```

However I want the same step for each line of data within 'match3g'. Therefore, I have tried using a 'For' loop as follows:

```
for line in match3g:
                regex2 = re.compile(r'\d+(?=(?:,[^,]+){4}$)',re.S)
                regexer2 = re.search(regex2, match3g)
                if regexer2 is not None:
                    regexer2 = regexer2.group()
                    regexer3 = ','.join(list(regexer2))
                    regexs2 = str(regexer3)
                    print "Test = ", regexs2.decode()
```

Instead of giving me the desired result, I get a print out like this:

```
Test - 0,0,0,0
Test - 0,0,0,0
Test - 0,0,0,0
Test - 0,0,0,0
....lots of lines of this
Test - 0,0,0,0
Test - 0,0,0,0
Test - 0,0,0,0
Test - 0,0,0,0
```

My expected output would be:

```
Test = 3,3,3,3
Test = 3,3,3,1
Test = 1,3,3,3
Test = 3,3,0,3
Test = 3,0,3,3
Test = 1,3,3,1
Test = 3,3,1,1
Test = 3,3,1,0
Test = 3,0,3,1
Test = 3,3,1,0
Test = 1,1,1,3
Test = 3,1,1,1
Test = 0,3,1,1
Test = 0,0,1,3
Test = 1,0,0,3
Test = 0,0,1,3
Test = 0,3,0,0
Test = 0,0,3,0
Test = 0,0,3,0
Test = 0,1,0,1
Test = 1,0,0,1
Test = 1,0,0,0
Test = 0,1,0,0
Test = 0,0,0,0
```

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong with this? It looks to me as if I am almost there.

Thanks

Comment: @hjpotter92 now i have got this far with doing it this way, I would rather try and fix the For loop rather than starting from scratch. the string is derived from using Scrapy rather than coming in from a .csv file.

Comment: what output do you expect?

Comment: The second code isn't working because you are still searching inside match3g, not `line`..   `re.search(regex2, match3g)` should be `re.search(regex2, line)`. Nonetheless, your main problem is with the regex you have. I suppose part of it is the $ sign, which most likely looks for end of file (by default). Maybe try building new regex [here](http://www.regexr.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for line in s.split("\n"):
    spl = line.rsplit(",",5)[-5:-4]
    if spl:
        print "Test = {}".format(",".join(list(spl[0])))
Test = 3,3,3,3
Test = 3,3,3,1
Test = 1,3,3,3
Test = 3,3,0,3
Test = 3,0,3,3
Test = 1,3,3,1
Test = 3,3,1,1
Test = 3,3,1,0
Test = 3,0,3,1
Test = 3,3,1,0
Test = 1,1,1,3
Test = 3,1,1,1
Test = 0,3,1,1
Test = 0,0,1,3
Test = 1,0,0,3
Test = 0,0,1,3
Test = 0,3,0,0
Test = 0,0,3,0
Test = 0,0,3,0
Test = 0,1,0,1
Test = 1,0,0,1
Test = 1,0,0,0
Test = 0,1,0,0
Test = 0,0,0,0
```

Comment: its a bit trickier than that. i want the string of numbers that on the line ',10272,2792,Alfreton,24,0000,21,00,23,00' would be '0000'. i then want to break that up so that it prints as '0,0,0,0'. i want this same step for all lines in the data above. thanks.

Comment: can you add the expected output to your question

Comment: i've amended it now. basically the purpose of this exercise is that once i have split the string up with commas I am going to use this to replace the original string with the new one. so in the data '1331' would become '1,3,3,1'. thanks

Comment: @user3045351, so you want the last five columns not 4?

Comment: cunnginham no, i only want the 5th from last column which is an unbroken string of digits. i then want to break this up using commas in a new string and replace the old one with the new. as that is quite a lot of steps i am just focusing on isolating the correct string for now. thanks

Comment: @user3045351, like now?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want this, if you want 0,0,0,0 instead of 0000.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import re

match3g = '''10272,201,Halifax,1,3333,1,33,2,33
,10272,989,Forest Green,2,3331,3,33,9,31
,10272,203,Lincoln,3,1333,6,13,4,33
,10272,206,Barnet,4,3303,11,30,1,33
,10272,199,Wrexham,5,3033,15,03,3,33
,10272,749,Kidderminster,6,1331,2,33,13,11
,10272,205,Macclesfield,7,3311,8,31,8,31
,10272,6106,Eastleigh,8,3310,7,31,10,30
,10272,1392,Aldershot,9,3031,5,31,12,03
,10272,921,Gateshead,10,3310,16,30,6,31
,10272,164,Grimsby,11,1113,18,11,5,13
,10272,991,Woking,12,3111,19,11,7,31
,10272,204,Torquay,13,0311,4,31,17,01
,10272,919,Southport,14,0013,14,03,18,01
,10272,185,Bristol Rovers,15,1003,9,13,22,00
,10272,909,Dover,16,0013,13,03,19,01
,10272,3551,Braintree Town,17,0300,10,30,20,00
,10272,1389,Altrincham,18,0030,12,03,21,00
,10272,213,Chester,19,0030,24,00,11,03
,10272,6140,Dartford,20,0101,20,01,15,10
,10272,1395,Welling,21,1001,17,11,24,00
,10272,982,Telford,22,1000,22,00,14,10
,10272,913,Nuneaton,23,0100,23,00,16,10
,10272,2792,Alfreton,24,0000,21,00,23,00'''


for line in match3g.split('\n'):
    a = line.split(',')
    if a[0]=='':
        print list(a[5])
    else:
        print list(a[4])
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. this throws up the error: ' exceptions.IndexError: list index out of range'

Comment: @user3045351 I've updated my answer. Try again and tell me if it works.

Comment: @m170897017...exact syntax i used was: 'for line in match3g.split('\n'):
    a = line.split(',')
    if a[0]=='':
        print list(a[5])
    else:
        print list(a[4])'

Comment: @user3045351  Which line throws an IndexError?

Comment: it is when it gets the end of the file. so in an example where there are 24 records it is if the code is trying to parse a 25th line, at which point it errors. thanks

Comment: @user3045351 Can you show me content of 25th line? Does it have the same format like 24th line?

Comment: @m170897017...there is no 25th line....it is a 24 line string, but the code continues on as if it is expecting further lines, which falls over because it is then out of range.

Comment: i think i might just want 'print list(a[4])' without the if statement. will try now.

Comment: no, i still require the if statement, just for some reason this logic is attempting to parse more rows than are in the data.

Comment: @user3045351 Are you adding another \n after 24th line? It will get 25 lines by split('\n').

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite after comments with OP:

I'm not so comfortable with Python, so sorry if I'm wrong on the python part:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import re

match3g = '''10272,201,Halifax,1,3333,1,33,2,33
,10272,989,Forest Green,2,3331,3,33,9,31
,10272,203,Lincoln,3,1333,6,13,4,33
,10272,206,Barnet,4,3303,11,30,1,33
,10272,199,Wrexham,5,3033,15,03,3,33
,10272,749,Kidderminster,6,1331,2,33,13,11
,10272,205,Macclesfield,7,3311,8,31,8,31
,10272,6106,Eastleigh,8,3310,7,31,10,30
,10272,1392,Aldershot,9,3031,5,31,12,03
,10272,921,Gateshead,10,3310,16,30,6,31
,10272,164,Grimsby,11,1113,18,11,5,13
,10272,991,Woking,12,3111,19,11,7,31
,10272,204,Torquay,13,0311,4,31,17,01
,10272,919,Southport,14,0013,14,03,18,01
,10272,185,Bristol Rovers,15,1003,9,13,22,00
,10272,909,Dover,16,0013,13,03,19,01
,10272,3551,Braintree Town,17,0300,10,30,20,00
,10272,1389,Altrincham,18,0030,12,03,21,00
,10272,213,Chester,19,0030,24,00,11,03
,10272,6140,Dartford,20,0101,20,01,15,10
,10272,1395,Welling,21,1001,17,11,24,00
,10272,982,Telford,22,1000,22,00,14,10
,10272,913,Nuneaton,23,0100,23,00,16,10
,10272,2792,Alfreton,24,0000,21,00,23,00'''


regex2 = re.compile(r'^(?:,|)(?:.*?,){4}(\d+),.*$',re.M)
for (line) in match3g.split('\n'):
  print line
  match = re.search(regex2, line)
  print list(match.group(1))
```

Comment: unfortunately no, the field length will vary massively depending on what data I am parsing. thanks

Comment: Is the field lenght predictible and same lenght within the resultset ? (if yes you can create the regex with the number of repetitions, but it involves a more specific regex, I'll see if can find something with recursion)

Comment: @tesibai...unfortunately no...it will always be in the same place, but the length will vary a lot.

Comment: Should be better now, takes always the 4th field (even if the line starts with a coma)